# How to add buddypress sub-menu items to other menus

Tags: menus, buddypress

I want to use BPs sub menu items in other menus.

By default you get following items to drop them in menus;

- Activity
- Notifications
- Profile
- Logout

I want to add "Profile -> Edit" to the list.

In my theme's functions.php:

```
// Adds buddypress menu item to the backend's menues section
function buddyboss_child_bp_nav_adder2() {
    global $bp;

    bp_core_new_nav_item(
        array(
            'name' => sprintf( __( 'Edit', 'my-trans' ) ),
            'slug' => 'profile/edit',
            'position' => 20,
            'show_for_displayed_user' => true,
            'screen_function' => 'buddyboss_child_list',
            'item_css_id' => 'profileedit',
            'default_subnav_slug' => 'profile-edit'
            //'parent_url'    => $bp->displayed_user->domain,
            //'parent_slug'   => $bp->profile->slug,
        ));
}
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'buddyboss_child_bp_nav_adder2' );
```

The Item now appears in the site's content buddypress menu and also in the backend so I can drop it into menus. But it won't appear on the frontend menu.

```
'slug' => 'profile/edit'
```

This causes the trouble. Dont know why.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with this Plugin. Works great!
https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-direct-menus/installation/